# Compiler Error in Unity v2020.3 when trying to run Unity ML Agents package, what is the issue?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

[image]

**Issue**

I have no idea what's the issue I'm using Unity 2020.3, i'd narrowed down the error to the MLagents package manager download (depending on the version I get a whole different # of errors like when I install mlagetns 2.00 I get 30 errros whereas using 1.04 only 1 error)

**Actual Error Code**:

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.5.0-dev-20359-01 (8da8ba0c)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:/Unity/MLAgentsMainCompMLTut/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@1.0.7/Plugins/ProtoBuffer/Grpc.Core.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:/Unity/MLAgentsMainCompMLTut/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@1.0.7/Plugins/ProtoBuffer/System.Interactive.Async.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:/Unity/MLAgentsMainCompMLTut/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@1.0.7/Plugins/System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:/Unity/MLAgentsMainCompMLTut/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@1.0.7/Plugins/System.IO.Abstractions.dll' could not be found
**
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello dear if you find this issue so you have to close your project and save the project then start to again project open, this is right solution for your issue.